# New calculated column based on removing spaces between character strings from another column

Tags: ms-access

I have a column in a table that contains people's names. I want to create a computed column that removes all the spaces in a given person's name and then takes the first four characters of their name.

Please see attached screenshot for an illustration. Column A contains people's names. What I have managed to end up with is in Column B (which is incorrect) by using the Left function. As you can see, it includes the spaces as one of the four characters. What I want is in Column C.

[image: MS Access Question Example]

When I tried to create a computed column using the Replace function to replace " " with "", MS Access throws up an error stating that the expression cannot be used in a calculated column. Hence, I am unable to combine the Replace function with the Left function.

Help needed. Much appreciated!

Comment: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: So you want what? The first 4 letters excluding spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is only a part of what you're trying to accomplish with these names (and perhaps an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHhLtm.png)).  For example, what are you going to do about multiple employees with the same abbreviation?

Anyhow...

### The right way *(via query)*

```
SELECT Left(Replace([Name]," ",""),4) AS NewName FROM Table1;
```

[image: img]

---

### How you want to do it *(via calculated field)*

I spent a 20+ minutes trying various ways to get this working in a calculated table field (to provide an alternate, but not-recommended, solution) before giving up.  I couldn't find any combination of built-in functions that will work since various functions are simply *not available* in calculated fields, for various reasons.

> ### *"Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables."*
>
> *— [Quote from **Allen Brown**](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html#CalcFieldA2010), Microsoft MVP* and *"t̲h̲e̲" Excel Guru.*

---

- There *is* a section of [this page](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html#CalcFieldA2010) titled ***"You want to store a calculated result anyway?"***
  <sub>(...but don't come crying to us when you regret it later!)</sub> ☺
- You're not the first person who was determined to use calculated fields in an Access table.
  [Here's a few thousands posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22microsoft%20access%22%20problems%20with%20%22calculated%20fields%22&num=100&tbs=li:1) from people who decided it was a terrible idea.

(I heard a rumour that Microsoft is planning of finally going to remove `Calculated` from the table `Data Type` drop-down with the next release of Access.)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted an answer via a calculated field in a table instead of a query though. Guess it cannot be done in a table and thanks for highlighting to me about the calculated field method violating table normalization standards. Much appreciated!

Comment: @DTYK I added more information about calculated fields to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50085011/8112776).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. I will think of a way to revamp the database in such a way that the calculated field will end up on the query instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

André and Tim are right: Use a query and an expression similar to Tim's:

```
Select *, Left(Replace([Name], " ", ""), 4) As Name4
From YourTable
```